# How to fix animation distortion?

Tags: animation, armature

I'm completely new to 3D modeling and animation, so please cut me some slack. I've downloaded and imported a free 3D model. Added a bone structure (armature) to it and now I'm trying to create a basic animation.

All is working perfectly fine so far, except that I seem to get some kind of distortion (not sure if this is correct naming for it) when animating the model. Here are 2 screenshots to show what I mean:

Original position:
[image: Model original position]

Animated position:
[image]

How do I either prevent or fix this? Has it something to do with the bone affect range and is it a simple matter of adding more bones or is it not that easy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a weight-painting issue.  Keep one of those selected bones in the screenshot selected, select the mesh and get into Weight Painting Mode.  You'll probably see a ring of green, yellow around the mouth/gums.

Comment: You're right. But as I said in my question, I'm completely new to all of this. So do you mind explaining in more detail as to how to proceed from there? If it's to much to explain, I don't mind if you just comment some kind of tutorial and I can help myself from there :)

Comment: Never mind. I've searched a couple of tutorials about weight painting and I'm getting the hang of it. Thanks a lot for pointing me into the right direction!